# regex for alphanumeric with parentheses ()

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, alphanumeric

i have a jQuery regex for alphanumeric of 6 to 255 length and i want to check for brackets "()" and other characters like underscore, comma, hyphen,

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9,., ,_,-,\(\)]{6,255}$/
```

but there is something wrong with it in terms of brackets and it is also accepting script values which is not good in terms of security

As I explain better in a comment below, some strings that are ok:

```
ABCDEF
ABCDEFG
abcdef
0123456789
a.b.c.d.e
., _-()
```

Some strings that aren't ok

```
ABC
ABCDEF(
Abcdef(ghi
abcde)fgh
```

(the last two ones aren't ok because the brackets aren't matched)

Comment: Can you add examples of strings it accepts that you don't want it to accept?

Comment: _jQuery regex_. What it? And what it's _check_? Check if exist or not exist, only these chars exist or... ?

Comment: @AndrewD. `dot` must be escaped only outside of `[]`, not inside.

Comment: examples of teh string include :
nida_ali is starting a new-business with the  name NV(clothing). this is just an example , shown here.

Answer (score 0):

```
/(?=^([^()]*\([^()]*\))*[^()]*$)^[A-Za-z0-9,. _()-]{6,255}$/;
```

You are checking too many times for `,` and the `-` must be the last character or be escaped (`\-`), otherwhise it's used as a range (`A-Z`)

I've added a precheck to test that all the `(` have a `)` and all the `)` have a `(`. It won' work with `(())` (two levels of brackets)

Test here: http://jsbin.com/epiroh/8/edit and http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2uuab

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you can also escape the `-` character (like `/^\-$/`)

Comment: @cambraca "or be escaped" (I have now added an example of what I meant) And you need to escape the `-` only inside `[...]`, not outside.

Comment: You don't have to escape `()` in the character class.

Comment: @cambraca: `-` just has special meaning inside `[]`.

Comment: the [link] (http://regexr.com?2uu9p) is not working :( plus its the regex of a feedback text-area so i think feedback should support this

Comment: @user958414 regexr is producing illegal links (they give out links using the domain regexr.com but they are still using gskinner.com. Corrected.

Comment: /^[A-Za-z0-9,. _\(\)-]{6,255}$/ regex is excepting single bracket "(" aswell ... which it shouldnt........ plus the link http://regexr.com?2uu9p is not working

Comment: @xanatos i have tried ur jsbin tool(jsbin.com/epiroh/edit) n it is also excepting single brackets as i have taken a screen shot as well

Comment: this was my string 
"dfdffdsdj-skadn787_kjbsd( jsdi sdh" and it showed true......

Comment: @user958414 What do you mean with "single brackets"? What string gives you problems?

Comment: @user958414 Tested. It works: http://jsbin.com/epiroh/3/edit press **render** button

Comment: it shouldn't be excepting one brackets like "(" or ")" . what is should except is **(hello)** or **hello (sarah) hi how are you** but NOT **hudfh (idlfhdhf dkjfid**.........

Comment: @user958414 Ah... Now it's more clear! You shoud learn to write correct questions with examples. It's quite more complex then.

Comment: @user958414: If xantos helped you, consider upvoting this answer or accepting it using the icons left of the answer.